# CSS columns not working with website, I tried changing the column widths but that didn't fix it. Any suggestions?

Tags: html, css

[Media and Phases Columns should be swapped and not coliding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqktB.jpg)

I'm assuming there's something wrong with either my [HTML](https://github.com/PR0G4M3R/-user-.github.io/blob/main/index.html) or [CSS](https://github.com/PR0G4M3R/-user-.github.io/blob/main/style.css) code.

I just implemented the columns and expected it to work the same as in the test but I must have  done something wrong.

Comment: Pleasz use a stackoverflow snippet with a [**minimal** and reproductible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),_because this is the best way to get answers..._

Comment: Please always post code in the question itself, not through external links, so the question does not become useless if the link dies. For more best practices, see **[ask]**.

Comment: Use flex grid for page layout instead of floats. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: You might like to put your code through a validator first just to check whether there are any errors (there are). Correct those and see whether you still have the problem. If so, put the code direct into your question with a description of what isn't working in the way you require.

Answer (score 0):

I've found several mistakes in the markup, here is the list of fixes:

1. Add correct closing tag for `<footer>` - use `</footer>` instead of `<footer>`
2. Add quotes("") around the value of `href` attribute in `<a>`s
3. Add closing tags for both `<div class="row">`

Here is the final markup with fixes applied:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Welcome To Project Echo</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/download-favicon.jpg" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img
      src="Images/IMG-3281.GIF"
      alt="Echo Logo"
      width="250"
      height="200"
      class="logo"
    />
    <h1 class="”title”">Welcome To Project Echo</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <h3>What is Project Echo?</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column2">
        <p>
          Project Echo is a multi-phase project I started using my coding
          skills.
        </p>
        <h2>It consists of four phases:</h2>
        <table style="width: 400px">
          <tr>
            <th>Phase 1:</th>
            <th>Phase 2:</th>
            <th>Phase 3:</th>
            <th>Phase 4:</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Online Presence</td>
            <td>Discord Bot</td>
            <td>Desktop Application</td>
            <td>Mobile Application</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <h2>
          I am are currently on phase 1, but hope to move to the next phase
          soon.
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">
        <h2>Media</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="https://github.com/PR0G4M3R" target="_blank">Github</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://discord.gg/9eHjheQ6mU" target="_blank">Discord</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@pr0g4m3r_og" target="_blank"
              >TikTok</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>

        <h4>More Coming Soon!</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <h4>© Project Echo 2023, all rights reserved.</h4>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```